# Attachments in Message Templates

Tags: message-templates, attachments

How do I attach documents to a message template? Am I overlooking an "attach" button?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that's not possible yet (it would be a good feature to add to CiviCRM).
Adding attachments is only possible sending an email or bulk email, not when you create/edit a message template.

You could upload the file/attachment to your server/site and include a link that points to it in the message template so recipients can download it.

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled on an extension for this: https://civicrm.org/extensions/e-mail-template-attachments

Although, I'm having a little trouble with it maybe you'll have more luck.

Comment: This seems to work, though with a few caveats. Have you used it in anger. See https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/33675/adding-email-attachments-from-saved-files-rather-than-uploading

Answer (score 0):

When you do Actions> Phone Call, there is the Attachment(s) section at the bottom of the screen. You can add files here. You can then send an e-mail with the file attachment to the person or mail group you assign to Assigned to. Your Phone Call will go as a message template.